Finding a YA book about a boy with powers
I’m looking for a book I read maybe 12 or 13 years old. The cover was blue with characters using powers on it and one of them was girl with black hair with blue streaks.
The characters were in a club of people who had powers (I think they could create things they could imagine). The club was attacked one day and the teacher was abducted.
I remember the girl having a thing for lightning and the boy creating a tornado. There was also a character who would pick locks with his power. They possibly could have needed some sort of artifact or something to focus but that im not 100 percent on.
The boy was also tested for his powers by imagining fire and I think they could only use their powers in a containment thing in the beginning

"I’m looking for a book I read maybe 12 or 13 years old." Do you mean that you read the book 12 or 13 years ago, i.e. 2011 or 2012? Or that you read it when you were 12 or 13 years of age? If you meant the latter, then in roughly which year did you read it?

@LogicDictates 12 years old so around 8 or 9 years ago.

Possibly Spell Robbers by Matthew Kirby?


After Ben Warner is recruited to join a "science camp" led by the eccentric quantum physicist Dr. Madeleine Hughes, he quickly realizes it's no regular science camp. Along with his new friend, Peter, Ben discovers the secret, powerful art of Actuation -- the ability to change reality by simply imagining it differently.
When a mysterious group of men invade Dr. Hughes's laboratory, abducting her and stealing her precious equipment, Ben and Peter are suddenly caught up in a turf war between dangerous actuators desperate for Dr. Hughes's innovative technology. And as Ben and Peter are pulled into a perilous, hidden world full of impossibilities now made possible, will their combined powers be enough to save Dr. Hughes and vanquish their enemies before it's too late?

I don't have a copy of the book to check the details, but the cover does show a girl with black hair that has blue streaks, and she does appear to have lightning powers. The precis mentions the teacher being kidnapped. The only thing that doesn't match is that the book is only ten years old so you couldn't have read it twelve years ago.

Thank you! I read it when I was around 12 or 13 which was about 8 years ago so this is definitely it.

@henri Please click on the tick mark to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)
